# Can I bind DbSet and BindingList together to display database contents in the ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, listbox

I use WinForms and Entity Framework 6. I have an:

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Person> People{ get; set; }
  }
```

Every `Person` has properties: `Id`,`Name`,`LastName`,`Age`.

In the `Form` I would like to display all the `People` in the `ListBox` and I would like to keep the contents of this `ListBox` synchronized with the database.

How to bind `BindingList bindingList` to the `ApplicationDBContext context`, or the other way around?

Comment: this is SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ToBindingList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696575(v=vs.103).aspx) extension method to get the `BindingList<Person>` you need as a `DataSource` in your `ListBox`:

```
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    private YourContext context=new YourContext();

    public BindingList<Person> BindingList { get; set; }


    private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        context.People.Load();
        this.listBox1.DataSource= BindingList= context.People.Local.ToBindingList();
        this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }

    //Button for save new changes
    private void SaveChangesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    //Disposing the context before close the form
    private void YourForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
    { 
        context.Dispose(); 
    } 
}
```

When an object is added or deleted from the `DbSet` it will also be added or removed from the `BindingList`. Adding or Removing from the `BindingList` will also perform the corresponding Add/Remove on the `DbSet`.

Comment: How to select specific person from bindinglist and return person entity